# Countable Set Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=$ $\{$ $(x_1,x_2,x_3....)$: $x_i\in \mathbb{Q}$ $\forall i$ and $\exists$ $k>0$ such that $l>k$ $\implies$ $x_{l}=x_{l+1}$ $\}$

Show that the set is countably infinite.

I'm not sure how to do this, may someone help? I'm not sure where to start as well.

Comment: Encode these sequences in finite tuples by sending $(x_1,x_2,...)$ to $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ where $x_{n-1}\neq x_n$, but $x_n=x_m$ for all $m\geq n$. The set of finite tuples is just $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Q}^n$, which is a countable union of the countable sets $\mathbb{Q}^n$. So, your set is being mapped injectively into a countable set.

Comment: Do you know that the set of finite sequences of naturals is countable?  Chop off the constant tail and you have the set of finite sequences of rationals.  Now map the rationals to the naturals and you are done.

Comment: @RossMillikan may you please elaborate in the answers below, please?

Comment: @conditionalMethod So I define a map $f: A\rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1} \mathbb{Q}^n$ by $f((x_1,x_2,x_3.....,x_n,q,q,q,q,q,q…)=(x_1,x_2,x_3.....,x_n)$. Is injective,right?

Comment: Yes, for $x_n\neq q$.