# Showing that two tuples are equal

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a function $$g:A\rightarrow\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}\mathbb{Q}^n.$$ Here, $A$ is the set of sequences $t_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ that are eventually constant. We define $t_k=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n,x_k,x_k,x_k,...)$, and the function by $f(t_k)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$. I am trying to show that this is injective.

If we take $t_a,t_b\in A$, then how does $f(t_a)=f(t_b)\implies t_a=t_b$.

Comment: $x_a$ and $x_b$ are elements in their own tuples?

Comment: What's your definition of equality of a tuple? Like when are two tuples equal?

Comment: @BrianTung Apologies, I have since edited my question

Comment: @Anvit Question has been edited.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but what do you think about the sequences $0, 0, 0, \dots$ and $1, 1, 1, \dots$?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I am not sure what you mean. If it helps, my question was from a larger problem found here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462919/countable-set-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question as there is several issues. You use $x_a,x_b$ for elements of a sequence and for full sequence which is confusing. Moreover, $f$ is probably not injective if I understand well what you wrote: two sequences with same initial terms but different eventually constant values will have the same image.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Has my edit helped? If not, I will try to improve my response further.

Comment: Yes this is better. And $f$ is not injective as $f(0, 0, 0, \dots) = f(0, 1, 1, \dots) = (0)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Oh no. It was stated that it was indeed injective in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462919/countable-set-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1 What if I define $x_n\neq x_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

The $f$ you defined is not one-one (With a counterexample already mentioned in the comments). Rather define $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,q,q,q,\cdots)=(x_1,\cdots,x_n,q)$. It is easy to see that this $f$ is bijective.

We want to show that $f$ is injective. I.E., if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$. First of all, if $f(a)=f(b)$, then both must be of equal length (i.e. both must belong to $\mathbb Q^{n+1}$ for a fixed $n\in\mathbb \{0,1,...\}$). Now that we've established both are of equal length, tuple equality means that every element of the tuple is equal. By reconstruction of $a$ and $b$, we see that $a$ and $b$ must be equal

Comment: What would be the domain and codomain of the map $f$?

Comment: @StevenH Same as $g$ you defined in the question

Comment: Oh. Are you able to show me how it is injective? I have tried, but I don't understand

Comment: Sure, I'll Edit that in. Give me a moment